# Facebook data exchange for mobile games (multiplayer)

Tags: multiplayer, mobile, facebook

A multiplayer mobile game that we are working on connects players through Google Play and Game Center but we would also like to add an option to play with your Facebook friends and here's the question:

Is there a way to exchange the data between Facebook users through the FB API so we could exchange Google Play ID / Game Center ID?

Is there a way to do this without having a server which holds Facebook UIDs and stuff?

Comment: What do you mean by "*exchange the data between Facebook users through the FB API so we could exchange Google Play ID / Game Center ID*"? Have you read the Facebook API docs?

Comment: For example - is there a way to call GET request to intercept Facebook game request messages through the application?

And yes, I did read Facebook API docs.